# ImageMagick PNG Poor Quality

Tags: imagemagick, png

I need to take and image, size it down and crop it - then overlay another transparent mask PNG and mask the image below. I have this ImageMagick code that works well and achieves what I need, however, some of the images (not all) come out very poor quality with visible artifacts. I assume I am not outputting the highest quality PNG 24? I need the output as high quality as possible regardless of file size. Any ideas how I can achieve this? Attached are sample images.

`exec(" convert \( upload.png -resize 100x60^ -gravity center -extent 100x60 \) icon_template.png -alpha on -compose CopyOpacity -composite -quality 100 icon.png ");`

Original upload.png:

[image]

icon_template.png:

[image]

Output icon.png

[image]

Comment: Please make life easier for anyone answering your questions by ensuring all your images are uploaded individually (not all merged into one) and that the separate images mentioned in your code are identifiable as to which is which. And which is an input, which is an output, what the actual result is and what the expected result is. Thank you.

Comment: Understood - Edited the post

Comment: Which one corresponds to `upload.png` please? And which one is `icon_template.png`?

Comment: Ok I included all the exact original source images

Comment: And how does it look when it works... in the normal case?

Comment: Sometimes it just renders a perfect image as you can see here https://cryptopixel.app/images_map_icons/07030532.png. I can't pinpoint what it is that creates the bad image vs. the good image

Comment: I'm struggling with what your command is actually supposed to do... with what effect it is supposed to create.

Comment: Not all icons created are square. Sometimes they are odd shapes and need to be masked with transparent parts of the image. Like you see here MASK: https://cryptopixel.app/images_icons_templates/53ef5203.png RESULT: https://cryptopixel.app/images_map_icons/53ef5203.png - This part of the script is working

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Your command cannot overlay a colored image into the alpha channel. Your grid icon image is opaque. Please show a correct result (and if necessary the corresponding input and icon that you want to overlay or put into the alpha channel). P.S. -quality works different for PNG. So -quality 100 may not be correct. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

Comment: Also your image sizes do not correspond to the sizes in your command.  And your input is JPG not PNG.

Comment: Well I really don't know what I am doing. But the upload.png in my code example just represents whatever image file is uploaded. The fix I posted below actually works perfectly in all scenarios - but Im sure there is a better solution out there

Comment: I should also mention that the width/hight are dynamically entered based on template icon size

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out, albeit a bit of a hack. Turns out the mask code I needed to mask icons with transparency would mess up the icons without transparency. So I had to condition the code and detect which icons were fully opaque and which were not. So here is what I did.

Original Code:
`exec(" convert \( upload.png -resize 100x60^ -gravity center -extent 100x60 \) icon_template.png -alpha on -compose CopyOpacity -composite -quality 100 icon.png ");`

Solution:

returns true/false:
`$opacity_check = exec("convert icon_template.png -format '%[opaque]' info: ");`

`$opacity_code = ($opacity_check == "true") ? "" : "icon_template.png -alpha on -compose CopyOpacity -composite";`

`exec(" convert upload.png -resize 100x60^ -gravity center -extent 100x60 {$opacity_code} icon.png ");`